# How to give class to a host element in Angular 2 with @hostbinding

Tags: css, typescript, angular

I want to give a class to the host element of my component so until now I used the `host` property like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'left-bar',
  host: { 'class': 'left-bar' },
  templateUrl: 'app/left-bar/left-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/left-bar/left-bar.component.css']
})
export class LeftBarComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now though I'm getting a warning from TypeScript that this is a bad practice.

```
[tslint] In the "@Component" class decorator of the class "LeftBarComponent" you are using the "host" property, this is considered bad practice. Use "@HostBindings", "@HostListeners" property decorator instead.
```

How can I add a class to the host element in a more correct way and get rid of this warning?

Thx!

Update: Based on the answer below: I get the class but the style is not affecting the parent host element after the class is added.
My style is quite simple:

```
.left-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #323232; }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Angular2 style guide says to prefer `@HostBinding`, but this doesn't make `host: {...}` a bad thing.

You can use

```
@Component({
  selector: 'left-bar',
  templateUrl: 'app/left-bar/left-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/left-bar/left-bar.component.css']
})
export class LeftBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class.left-bar') leftBarClass = true;
  // or @HostBinding('class') leftBarClass = 'left-bar';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Thx, that adds the class but when I do this my style is not affecting the host element.

Comment: Did you check in the browser devtools if the class is actually added? Maybe your styles aren't right.

Comment: Yes the class is added and I verified that the style is right. It works for all the child elements but not for the host element.

Comment: If the class is visible in the devtools and the styles aren't applied, then the styles can't be right. Where do you add the styles (parent component, component itself, index.html, ...)?

Comment: In the `'app/left-bar/left-bar.component.css'` I have just this: `.left-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #323232; }
`

Comment: I guess it's better to edit your question and add the CSS and other additional info there

Comment: Where is `app/left-bar/left-bar.component.css` added?

Comment: Question updated. The css is added as you can see above at the @component styleUrls

Comment: You don't need to add a class to host to apply styles to it. Just `:host { position: fixed; width: 120px; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; background: #323232; }` (without adding `left-bar`) should do what you want.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks. I'll accept the answer also.

Comment: Great! Adding a class using `@HostBinding()` is when you have styles on the parent component that should be applied to your component (for example depending on it's internal state reflected to added or removed classes)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer @HostBinding('class') siteNavbarSmallClass = 'login-form login-form-second page-login-second'; it works for me also! thanks :)